# Python3. How to correctly raise exception inside context manager to handle it out of with operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, contextmanager

I want to catch exception that was raised inside context manager. I created simple example to reproduce the problem.

So, my context manager:

```
class Test(object):
    def div(self, a, b):
        return a // b
    def __enter__(self):
        print('enter')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')
        return self
```

And class where I want to use it:

```
class Container(object):
    def test_exc(self, a, b):
        try:
            with Test() as test:
                try:
                    result = test.div(a, b)
                    print(a, '/', b, '=', result)
                    return result
                except Exception as e:
                    raise e
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Usage:

```
c = Container()
c.test_exc(5, 1)
c.test_exc(5, 0)
```

The output:

```
enter
5 / 1 = 5
exit
enter
exit
```

So, when exception raised (in example above it's `ZeroDivisionError`) it's not catched by parent try...catch. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is the implemetation of your `__exit__()` function.

The documentation states:

> returning a true value from this method will cause the with statement
>   to suppress the exception and continue execution with the statement
>   immediately following the with statement. Otherwise the exception
>   continues propagating after this method has finished executing.
>   Exceptions that occur during execution of this method will replace any
>   exception that occurred in the body of the with statement.

just remove the

```
return self
```

from the `__exit__()` function.
Having no return will return `None` which evaluates as `False`

Answer (score 1):

I think that context managers can optionally pass on exceptions that they catch.

To stop exceptions, the `__exit__` method should return `True` (and `self` might count as `True`)

To pass exceptions on, return `False`:

```
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('exit')
        return False
```

See this [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#id38) to the PEP where some pseudo code shows how the exception may be swallowed.